# How to check if BMP is a monochrome or not in SkiaSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, image-processing, skiasharp

I am new to SkiaSharp(mono/SkiaSharp) and looking for a way to validate if my bmp image is monochrome or not in .net core?
I am doing it something like this

```
var bmpImage = SKBitmap.Decode(contentData);
if(bmpImage.Info.BitsPerPixel != 1)
   throw new Exception(..)
```

The BitPerPixel always gives "32" , even for a monochrome image where I am expecting it to be "1".Kindly help

Comment: Which overload of Decode is that ?

Comment: Check the code with bitmap, jpeg, Tif, SVG, format. The format has it's own effect. I guess this code may work with bmp

Comment: @YvesDaoust public static SKBitmap Decode(byte[] buffer);  this one

Comment: And what's in buffer ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust it has a monochrome bmp image in it

Comment: If you don't help me, I can't help you.